# How to test if a Date object is equal to a specific date

Tags: javascript, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

What's the **best** (clearest, shortest, fastest, etc.) way to determine whether a `Date` object is equal to, say, July 4, 2012?

For example, this works but is rather verbose:

```
if (date.getFullYear() === 2012 && date.getMonth() + 1 === 7 && date.getDate() === 4)
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

(In my actual scenario, server-side code will be plugging in the specific date to test against. Also, the `date` comes from a jQuery UI datepicker and so will have a time component of 00:00:00.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a new date and compare the results of `getTime`:

```
var existingDate = new Date('2012', '6', '4');
new Date('2012', '6', '4').getTime() == existingDate.getTime();
```

Comment: In the second example, is '7/4/2012' guaranteed to be parsed as M/D/YYYY?

Comment: No, that's a good point. It's system- and locale-specific. You'd probably have better luck using `new Date('2012-07-04T00:00:00').getTime() == existingDate.getTime()` but it's generally best to use the separate-parameter construction. I think I'll just delete the second part. It's in the edit history if anyone wants to see it.